# discord.py: How to display number of servers bot is in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have tried to do this multiple times with no success.

Python Version: 3.6

discord.py: async

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```py
@client.command()
    async def servers():
        servers = list(self.client.servers)
        await client.say(f"Connected on {str(len(servers))} servers:")
        await client.say('\n'.join(server.name for server in servers))
```

Answer (score 1):

To set it as you bot's status, this would be an example:

```
f"over {len(client.guilds)} servers.
```

More info can be found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=presence#discord.Client.change_presence)

Answer (score 0):

`Client.servers` is an iterable of `Server` objects the bot is a member of.  You can get the length of that with `len`:

```
len(client.servers)
```

Comment: So I can get it using that, but how do I implement it (having my bot display it in the _playing_ section, next to its name?)

Comment: See [Changing presence discord status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287989/changing-presence-discord-status)

Answer (score 0):

Since I think that you are trying to put it as the Playing status, here's what I did for my bot(works perfectly on Python 3.6):
So you'll have your on_ready task to tell you when the bot is logged in:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is logged in.')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(client.guilds)} servers!"))
```

This will say Watching (amount of servers) servers! on your status, but for Playing status you can try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is logged in.')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"{len(client.guilds)} servers!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event #ready
async def on_ready():
    print('Servers connected to:')
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've defined the bot as `client`.

[`client.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client.guilds) is a list of [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Guild)s that your bot is in. 
To get the amount of items (in your case that's the number of servers) in a list, use `len(list)`.
 In your case, that would be `len(client.guilds)`.

Also seems like you're looking to set that as a status, see how to do so [on the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-the-playing-status) 
Don't change status in `on_ready()`! See the documentation link above for more info.

Answer (score 0):

try this @Avery B

````
@client.command()
async def serverlist(ctx):
x = ', '.join([str(server) for server in client.guilds])
y = len(client.guilds)
print("Server list: " + x)
if y < 40:
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Currently active on " + str(y) + " servers:", 
    description="```json\n" + x + "```", colour=0xFFFFF)
    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
````